# attach lambda to existing API GW cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to attach a lambda function in cloudformation to an existing API Gateway created in other template.

In the other template are exported some variables:

CreatedApiGW and CreatedApiGWParentId

```
FunctionTest:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: function-test
      CodeUri: cmd/
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref SecGroup
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref Subnet1
          - !Ref Subnet2
      

  ApiGatewayResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !ImportValue CreatedApiGW
      ParentId: !ImportValue CreatedApiGWParentId
      PathPart: "test"

  ApiGatewayMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !ImportValue CreatedApiGW
      ResourceId: !Ref ApiGatewayResource
      HttpMethod: "POST"
      AuthorizationType: "NONE"
      Integration:
        Type: "AWS"
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
        Uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${FunctionTest.Arn}/invocations"


  ApiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !ImportValue CreatedApiGW
```

I don't want create an API Gateway for each lambda.

I want attach some lambdas to my existing API Gateway.

My lambda not create the trigger to the API GW

Attach the lambda to the API GW

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll assume you have created the Api and want to import values exported in said template. I'll also assume you created a RestApi (In any case, both doc references will be at the end).

You'll need to export the value in the other stack, something like:

```yaml
Outputs:
  ApiGatewayId:
    Description: The ID of the api you just created
    Value:
      Ref: ApiGateway
    Export:
      Name:
        'Fn::Sub': '${AWS::StackName}-CreatedApiGW'
  ApiGatewayRootResourceId:
    Description: The security group ID to use for public web servers
    Value:
      'Fn::GetAtt':
        - ApiGateway
        - RootResourceId
    Export:
      Name:
        'Fn::Sub': '${AWS::StackName}-RootResourceId'
```

The import will look like this:

```yaml
Fn::ImportValue:
  !Sub "${ApiGwStackName}-CreatedApiGW"
```

and

```yaml
Fn::ImportValue:
  !Sub "${ApiGwStackName}-RootResourceId"
```

The rest of your code seems fine. You can create methods for any apigateway in your template, you'll only need the apigw id and root resource id.

After everything's created, the trigger will appear in the function page.

Reference:

- [Fn::ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)
- [AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi Return Values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#aws-resource-apigateway-restapi-return-values)